# react router v4 shows same component in modal as well as in background page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

[image]

After loading the modal when i refresh the page the component is open in a page rather than a modal.
at this moment when i refresh the page twice and go back using the back arrow of browser the component is shown inside the modal as well as in the background page.

Comment: Seems like you'd rather file an issue to react-training git repo, if you suspect it is a bug on their page

Comment: Sure, create an [issue on repository](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5872) of react-router  but not getting the appropriate solution. is anyone has the solution ?